# dropdown menu disappear if the link is clicked when the browser is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

my dropdown menu in navbar works fine when the browser is maximized but if i resize the browser to a mobile size then the dropdown menu does not show up as well as the menu button toggled up. here is my navbar code with dropdown. I am using bootstrap 3.when i clicked EBBL the dropdown menu does not show up and the whole navbar menu is toggled up.

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="<?php echo site_url('home/index')?>">BCTF</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse ">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo site_url('home/index')?>">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo site_url('home/show_about')?>">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo site_url('home/show_open_butterfly_park')?>">Open Butterfly Park</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" >EBBL<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home/show_ebbl')?>">About EBBL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Content 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Content 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Content 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Content 4</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo site_url('home/show_biography')?>">Biography</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="<?php echo site_url('home/show_gallery')?>">Gallery</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: i just figure out the problem that if i click the top right button in the picture then this <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse "> obtain aria-expanded="true" attribute and it changes to false when i click the dropdown menu. could you give me a solution please?

Comment: Post your demo(http://jsfiddle.net/).